# Redirecting to Dashboard(magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

On checkout page when customer try to login it is getting redirect to it's dashboard.

I have turned off this setting from Admin end i.e ( "Redirecting customer to dashboard after login : off " )

But still it is getting redirected to Dashboard

I think I need to make some updates in core.

Comment: Have you created custom login form ?

Comment: No. I am using by default login function on checkout page.